# Is there a way to change the direction of the Displace Modifier?

Tags: modifiers, displacement

[image]I want to use a displace modifier with a wave texture on a mesh, I have it working but it's diagonal to the mesh. Any way to change the orientation so it's vertical?

The orientation of the displacement is angular. I'd like it to run in vertical lines. I was wondering if there is a way to adjust that angle.

Comment: Could you please show some screenshots, or even share your file? What does it give if you change the Direction? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: If you use Normal for  Direction, then the displacemnt will always perpendicular to the faces. If you want to change the pattern's orientation you can use UV as Coordinates, and adjust the UVMap as you want in the UV editor.

Comment: Quick edit for more info. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can put the texture into the Object space of an Empty (or anything else), and transform the Empty as you choose.

[image]

But really, I still can't think of a good reason not to [use a simple GN modifier instead](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276226/35559).. you get so much more control.

Comment: Thanks, I've never attempted Geo Nodes and it's only a small part of the scene, but I might try it and see how it goes.

Comment: @elCamsterino 'I don't want the hassle of learning GN for a small part of my job' sounds like a good reason to me :D