# Displace modifier with cloud texture but only on X and Y axis

Tags: modifiers

Is there a way to displace vertex of a object with displace modifier but only on X and Y axis. I dont want Z axis to be moved at all.

Comment: Hello, what does it give if you stack two Displace, one on X, a second on Y

Comment: @moonboots yeah, that does a trick. Thank you

Comment: Or.. set it to XYZ to RGB and dial Z to 0 in a color version of the texture. It  gives positive XY on both sides of the object, though.. for full control, it's much [easier to use GN](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276226/35559), IMO

Answer (score 3):

Stack two *Displace* modifiers, one on X, a second on Y